# Memory issues with Qt5

Tags: c++, qt5, heap-memory

I am writing an application in which i read values from a csv file. Each line is splitted where the comma is is stored in a vector. Each line has 4 values. Then i store each value to an other vector. The csv file has 5.795.857 lines. So in my structure i want to store 4*5.795.857 values. The problem is tha the application crushes. As i see with the debuger i crushes approximately at the 405.000 line. I know my computer is a little bit old, but i think that it should be able to store this amount of values. I run Qt5 on WindowsXP 32bit and i have 1GB ram.

I am new to Qt and c++ programming but as a java developer when i have such problems i increase the heap size. You think this is my problem? If yes how can i increase the heap size at Qt5?

This is my code that reads the file and stores it in the data structure

```
std::vector  < std::vector < QString> >  Server::loadCsvFile( const char* path )
{
  vector <QString> temp;
  vector  <vector <QString> > dataFlow;
  string dataString;
  QString row;
  ifstream dataFile( path );

  int stopCounter = 0;

  //while((dataFile.good()) && (stopCounter < 1095))
  while (dataFile.good())
  {
    stopCounter++;
    getline( dataFile, dataString );
    row = QString::fromStdString( dataString );
    //cout << "counter: " << stopCounter << "\n";
    QStringList rowList = row.split( "," );

    for(  int i=0; i < rowList.size(); i++ )
    {
      temp.push_back( rowList.at(i));
    }

    dataFlow.push_back( temp );
    temp.clear();
    rowList.clear();
  }

  dataFile.close();
  dataFlow.pop_back();

  return dataFlow;
}
```

Until now i made some changes to see this fixes my problem, but nothing. This is how it looks my code know:

```
std::vector < QStringList > Server::loadCsvFile2( const char* path )
{
    std::vector < QStringList > dataFlow;
    QFile file(path);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        throw std::runtime_error("Can't open the file " +
                                 std::string(path));
    QTextStream in(&file);
    int counter = 0;
    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
        counter++;
        dataFlow.emplace_back(in.readLine().split(","));
        cout << counter << "\n";
    }
    return dataFlow;
}
```

Comment: What is the average length (approximately) of each line of your CSV file ? 4*5M = 20M strings is a lot of data, if each string is about 500 characters long you consumed your whole Gb around the 405000th element.

Comment: This is an example of the first line: 20121215,4000039_14,9,24 . The rest of the line are similar to this one

Comment: And what are you storing them in ? a `vector<string>` ? Has Qt anything to do with that part of the code ?

Comment: Does it always crash at the exact same line ? Maybe you should try to display every item you read and push, to see if something strange happens here. At first sight, you program seems correct.

Comment: Actually it does not crushes. At first it gets very slow and after a while it says not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a `std::vector` consists in three elements :

- a size
- an array of elements
- a capacity

The capacity is the number of elements the vector can currently hold, and it is the actual size (in RAM) of your array. The size is the number of elements you really have in your vector. For instance, when you create an empty `vector<int>`, its size is 0, its capacity is 10 (or something else, I don't know) and the array is consuming `10 * sizeof(int)`. If you `push_back` a value, then the size is 1 but the capacity or the array's actual size didn't change.

But when you have 10 elements in your vector and try to add one, something happens : the actual array is full (`vec.size() == vec.capacity()`) so the algorithm has to extend that capacity :

- double the value for capacity,
- allocate a new array whose actual size is the new capacity ; in other words, allocate `20 * sizeof(int)` bytes,
- copy the content of the old array to the new array,
- free memory consumed by the old array,
- now, add the item as usual since there is room available.

Of course, you can now add up to 20 items, and adding a 21st will make the algorithm allocate for 40 items, and adding a 41st will make it allocate for 80 etc.

Usually, you don't really care about these internal details. But when you add lots and lots of items to a vector, things start to be problematic. The more the vector grows, the more new allocations and copies take time and consume RAM. In your situation, I suspect your 405 001th line makes the algorithm need to allocate for 810 000 elements, and copy from the first to the second and since RAM is running very low your OS is writing parts of it on the disk, which is *dead* slow.

You want the initial capacity of the array to be big enough to reduce the occurrences of reallocations. What you can do is call the `reserve` method and give it a big enough number to avoid too many allocations. However, I'm afraid you might not have enough RAM to achieve that process even this way.

Comment: nice expanation about vectors memory allocation. I used the reserver method but nothing seems to change. Also i make some calculations:  
4*5.795.857 = 23183428 lines // assuming every item has 4 characters:   23183428 * 1(should be one byte per char) * 4 = 92733712 bytes // 92733712 / 1024 = 90560 KB // 181120.5 / 1024 = 88.4375 MB // 
so if i am right it shouldn't be a memory problem (sorry for the format i was not able to add line breaks)